# Connect to an Oracle database through PHP

Tags: php, database, oracle, connection, oci8

I'm developing a PHP API that connects to an Oracle database, but unfortunately the connection does not work. First of all, I implemented the development environment (oracle database server + apache server), all well configured, I guess. The problem is that I do not get any response from the code I wrote, even when I type incorrect data.

PHP Info oci8:

```
[rvieira@localhost ~]$ php --ri oci8
oci8
OCI8 Support => enabled
Version => 1.4.10
Revision => $Id: 44bfa713983a99b3e59477f6532e5fb51b6dee94 $
Active Persistent Connections => 0
Active Connections => 0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 11.2.0.2.0
Oracle Instant Client Version => 11.2
Temporary Lob support => enabled
Collections support => enabled
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.events => Off => Off
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$connection = oci_connect('sys', 'rvieira', 'localhost/xe');

if (!$connection) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
?>
```

I also leave here the tutorials that I followed to configure the development environment:

- [Installing PHP and the Oracle Instant Client for Linux](http://oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html):
- [Oracle Database Express Edition Installation Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2) for Linux x86-64](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm)
- [Using PHP with Oracle Database 11g](http://oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm)

Comment: Have you looked at your server logs? They should tell you what is happening.

Comment: Well, I decided to run the php file via CLI and it runs and works, however, in the browser does not work. :|

http://alojaimagens.com/images/9grkq2kylfgaaiksbd.png

Comment: Mike W here it is:

[Sun Oct 13 23:24:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804\n in /var/www/html/api.php on line 2

[Sun Oct 13 23:25:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in /var/www/html/api.php on line 2

Answer (score 1):

Your error message suggests that there is a problem with the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but doesn't detail exactly what. Setting this is covered in step 6 of "Enabling the PHP OCI8 Extension on Linux", which you can find at your [first link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html).

Double check your installation - you've probably missed something.